# Do we need [help]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Just spotted a meaningless tag on the main site that I'm pretty sure we could do without.

[help](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help)

It's only been used on 3 questions so far, and doesn't really add anything, as I'm sure most everyone that posts a question is looking for help of some kind or another.

So, do we need [help](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a meaningless tag, like 'question'. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

Should we need to tag questions related to how to offer, accept, or reject help, the tag should be [helping](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/helping).

As the accepted answer reads, the tag [help](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) seems not very useful and should be removed.